# How to understand multithreading in tf queue?

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow provides us two ways to implement reading data.

The first way, use many readers, such as `tf.TextLineReader`, one reader per thread.

The second way, use just one reader and multithreading of enqueue ops, for example we can use `tf.train.shuffle_batch` and set `num_threads` greater than 1.

I can't understand the second way, we just have one reader to load data(perhaps a thread), why we need so many threads to enqueue?

And for the first way, we should use `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join`, there is no `num_threads` parameter we can set, so I think the first way is understandable.

Can anyone give me some explanation for why we need one reader but many threads to enqueue?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding they are only different in terms of input types. `tf.train.batch_join` accepts a list of samples while `tf.train.batch` is taking only one sample at a time.

In case of `tf.train.batch_join` the input samples to the queue are expected to be provided by one or more threads. So, the number of threads are implicitly controlled by means of the number of samples in the input. On the other hand, `tf.train.batch` has `num_threads` argument to be able to create multiple enqueue operations. The first argument `tensors` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) is initialized by several threads.

Using multiple enqueue threads hides the latency. Consider a simple scenario where the reader/function/operation that is responsible from enqueuing samples takes significant amount of time. In such cases having multiple threads can be life saver. The following code snippet gives an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

num_steps = 50
batch_size = 2
input_shape, target_shape = (2, 2), ()
num_threads = 4
queue_capacity = 10
```

`get_random_data_sample` function randomly generates an (input,target) pair with some random latency.

```
def get_random_data_sample():
    # Random inputs and targets
    np_input = np.float32(np.random.normal(0,1, (2,2)))
    np_target = np.int32(1)

    # Sleep randomly between 1 and 3 seconds.
    time.sleep(np.random.randint(1,3,1)[0])

    return np_input, np_target

# Wraps a python function and uses it as a TensorFlow op.
tensorflow_input, tensorflow_target = tf.py_func(get_random_data_sample, [], [tf.float32, tf.int32])
```

Note that `[tensorflow_input, tensorflow_target]` operations (i.e., the reader) are run by `num_threads` many threads. You can verify this by changing `num_threads` and observing the running time.

```
### tf.train.batch ###
batch_inputs, batch_targets = tf.train.batch([tensorflow_input, tensorflow_target], 
                                             batch_size=batch_size, 
                                             num_threads=num_threads, 
                                             shapes=[input_shape, target_shape], 
                                             capacity=queue_capacity)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.train.start_queue_runners()
start_t = time.time()
for i in range(num_steps):
    numpy_inputs, numpy_targets = sess.run([batch_inputs, batch_targets])
print(time.time()-start_t)
```

`inputs` has `num_threads` elements in the following example.

```
### tf.train.batch_join ###
inputs = [[tensorflow_input, tensorflow_target] for _ in range(num_threads)]
join_batch_inputs, join_batch_targets = tf.train.batch_join(inputs,
                                                    shapes=[input_shape, target_shape],
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    capacity=queue_capacity,)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.train.start_queue_runners()
start_t = time.time()
for i in range(num_steps):
    numpy_inputs, numpy_targets = sess.run([join_batch_inputs, join_batch_targets])
print(time.time()-start_t)
```

Multiple enqueue threads in `tf.train.batch` are effective in hiding the latency. You can play with `num_threads` and `queue_capacity`. Performances of both operations are very similar.

Comment: Oh, on my system, the first way(`tf.train.batch`) is faster than the second way(`tf.train.batch_join`), the first way costs a quarter of time of the second way. It is amazing! How to explain?

Comment: Both take 36-38 seconds on my system. I am using tensorflow 1.2 and running them on GPU. Note that I measure the performance separately. In other words, running different files.

Comment: Why using one reader but multithreading is also fast? I think one reader should be slower than many readers, because one reader can just reads one file once.

Comment: "`tf.train.batch` has `num_threads` argument to be able to create multiple enqueue operations. The first argument tensors (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) is initialized by several threads." The reader is run by many threads.

Comment: I don't think so, because we have only one reader. So I think one reader read examples from file, and many threads enqueue examples to the example queue. But just one reader to read file, so I think it is slower.

Comment: Let's have a look at the source code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L660 and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L678
`tensor_list_list` and `tensor_list` correspond to our inputs. May be I shouldn't say "initialized" but it is clear that the reader operation is called by many threads in `tf.train.batch`. As I said previously neither of them outperforms the other one.

Comment: From source code, we can see many enqueue ops are run by many threads (one enqueue per thread), it isn't mean `reader ops called by many threads`, There is only one reader, and this reader read examples from files and many threads put examples into the example queue.

Comment: How do you think the `reader` reads examples and then `many threads` put examples into the queue? The reader must read many samples to feed multiple threads. In my opinion each thread make a call to `reader` to fetch one sample so that it can enqueue. The `enqueue` operation is fulfilled only after `reader` is called. Hence, they are coupled. Note that the reader is just a function that you can run/call multiple times.

Comment: Do you think the internal implements of multi-reader and one reader with mutil-threads are the same?

Comment: I think I finally understand your question. You refer multiple input files and one reader per input file (for example) by saying `multi-reader`. In `one-reader` case, we still do parallel reads, but on the same source. As I said each thread makes a call to the `reader`. In `multi-reader` case, however, we have multiple readers (as you said) and each of them is called once on the corresponding source.  Please have a look at `TODO` comment at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L721 : they want to support parallel reads for `multi-readers`.